# Asp.net paging crashing on chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, timer

I have a timer control on my page and an image handler which is set on every timer refresh. After about two minutes of running my page the page crashes on chrome with the "Aw Snap message". Can anybody help me out ??

JS Code.

```
    var t
    function set_coordinates_up(event) {
        //Get final co-ordinates
        var pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("divCar").offsetLeft;
        var pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("divCar").offsetTop;
        var hdf = document.getElementById('HiddenField1')


        //Store event information in hidden feild
        if (hdf != null) hdf.value = t + " " + pos_x + " " + pos_y;

    }
    function set_coordinates_down(event) {
        //Get initial co-ordinates
        var pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("divCar").offsetLeft;
        var pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("divCar").offsetTop;
        t = pos_x + " " + pos_y
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug, you shouldn't be able to crash the tab process from your web page

Answer (score 0):

check if your tab is leaking memory for some reason by opening up Chromes Task manager... probable reasons would be an infinite loop somewhere.

Chrome pages usually crash (Snap!) when there is low memory on the system. I would worry about that too.. Make sure you dont have many other processes running either.

Keep us updated.

Comment: The memory seems to be increasing extremely fast before crashing.

Comment: well cant help you much there unless we see sm code.. but it definitely isnt a chrome bug...

Comment: sorry my guess is this os more of a javascript prob. I would expect to see the js code..